Reorder a grouped boxplot by median of one group
I have a data frame consisting of 3 columns: Site, Program, Result. Here a minimal repro dataset:
> TP <- data.frame(Site = as.factor(c("Coal", "Coal", "Coal", "Coal", "STP", "STP", "STP", "STP")), 
                 Program = as.factor(c("D", "D", "H", "H", "D", "D", "H", "H")),
                 Result = c(0.65, 0.58, 0.15, 0.10, 0.55, 0.53, 0.48, 0.49))
> TP
   Site      Program                Result
   <fct>     <chr>                  <dbl>

 1 Coal      D                      0.65
 2 Coal      D                      0.58
 3 Coal      H                      0.15
 4 Coal      H                      0.10
 5 STP       D                      0.55 
 6 STP       D                      0.53
 7 STP       H                      0.48 
 8 STP       H                      0.49

In reality there are 70000 rows, made up of 50 sites and two programs.
I have created a geom_boxplot where the x variable is 'Result' and the y variable is 'Site'. For each site, I have two boxplots that contain data from the two different programs (D and H). The Y-axis is currently sorted by the overall median of a particular site, regardless of the program.
> TP$Site <- reorder(TP$Site, TP$Result, FUN = median)
> ggplot(TP, aes(x = Result, y = Site)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = as.factor(Program)), outliers = FALSE)

I am trying to alter the graph so that the Y-axis is in descending order of sites that had the highest median for Program D. I would still like the corresponding boxplot for each site in Program H to be immediately below the boxplot for Program D, I just want the sites ordered by Program D. Some sites only have data from Program D, and I would ideally like them ordered appropriately on the y-axis too, even though they do not have data for Program H.
I have seen many solutions on Stack Overflow using order, reorder or arrange(dplyr). I have tried several of these suggestions with no luck.
I have successfully used 'reorder' (stats) in my existing code to order the data frame by the median of the results, but I cannot replicate that result for multiple inputs and orders. I then attempted to use 'order' (base) to overcome this, but I cannot come up with a solution for multiple orders. I then also attempted to use dplyr solutions, using a combination of group_by, mutate and arrange. I cannot get this to work either.
In the supplied repro dataset, 'STP' has a higher overall median than 'Coal'. But 'Coal' has a higher median for Program D, so I would want 'Coal' to be at the top of the boxplot.
Any help is much appreciated. Let me know if I can provide more info.

Try: TP <- mutate(TP, Site=reorder(Site, Result, median), .by=Program)

Hi @Edward. Thanks for the suggestion. That does work on the repro dataset that I provided, but unfortunately not on my actual dataset. The important difference is that in my actual dataset, there are differences in the sorting rank of site median vs. site*program median. In my current repro dataset there is no such difference. E.g. Site 'STP' may have a higher overall median than Site 'Coal', but site 'Coal' has a higher median for Program D specifically. I will edit my repro dataset to reflect.

One option would be to use an ifelse to reorder the Site using only values for D:
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  TP,
  aes(
    x = Result,
    y = reorder(
      Site,
      ifelse(Program == "D", Result, NA),
      FUN = median,
      na.rm = TRUE
    )
  )
) +
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(fill = Program),
    outliers = FALSE
  )



Hi @stefan, thanks for providing a solution. The code worked well for my actual dataset, although it has introduced a strange problem of sorting one particular site incorrectly. Specifically, it places site 'Lev' at the top of the Y-axis, even though its median is roughly in the middle of the group. After interrogation, I believe this is because 'Lev' has eight data points for Program D, while all other sites have nine data points. Can you think of any reason your provided code may act this way in this instance?

Hm. Don't think that this is related to the number of data points. But a possible issue with my code might arise if not all sites contain data for program D. Such sites will be placed at the top.

Hi @stefan. I added in a false data point to the data frame for 'Lev' site, bringing it up to 9 data points, and it fixed the issue. Don't ask me how or why, but it is enough of a solution for me at this stage. Also, all sites have data for Program D, so no issues there either. Thanks again for your help!
